# azure function powershell read from storage queue and write to storage table

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

So I'm trying to develop a function that would read data from an Azure Storage queue and write it to an Azure storage table. I can't seem to find anything relevant. I found the code to read the queue:

```
$in = Get-Content $triggerInput
Write-Output "PowerShell script processed queue message '$in'"
```

But there are no examples to write to the table, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently I did the same function and you can find the examples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/master/sample). You need the function `QueueTrigger-PowerShell`. hth

```
$json = Get-Content $triggerInput | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output "PowerShell script processed queue message '$json'"

$title = "PowerShell Table Entity for message {0}" -f $json.id
$entity = [PSObject]@{
  Status = 0
  Title = $title
}

$entity | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $outputTable
```

To control to which table to write data you can use function.json. For me row and partition keys were specified there:

```
{
  "type": "table",
  "name": "outputTable",
  "tableName": "pancakeTable",
  "connection": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
  "direction": "out",
  "partitionKey": "some value",
  "rowKey": "I don't remember what was here but it was some form of variable (guid) generated from the request by Azure"
}
```

This is my function.json, but originally it had partition and row key values hardcoded into it. Right now I'm using powershell to generate those (copy-pasted from another answer in this thread):

```
PartitionKey = $requestBody.room  
RowKey = get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s.ms"
```

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I needed. No idea why I couldn't find it. Brilliant!

Comment: I logged an issue in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-templates/issues/375) for improving doc across all our languages for all the various bindings we support. The matrix of language/binding combos is large, but we need to provide better guidance. Feel free to share on that issue any suggestions you might have on how we can improve this. Thanks.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the above is missing the PartitionKey and RowKey values? I can't get it to work if I don't specify those two values, which I understand need to be unique too, [as per the note here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#partitionkey-property).

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in the [PowerShell storage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-powershell-guide-full#how-to-add-table-entities), in order to write entities to table storage you need to provide a unique PartitionKey and RowKey value.  Because of this, unless you're managing RowKeys outside in whatever's calling your Function, I found a datetime stamp to be useful.  With this in mind, an incoming json body like this:

```
{
  "room": "Boardroom",
  "temp": "21.24"
}
```

feeds into your PowerShell function (both WebHook and Queue trigger examples provided):

```
# WebHook example
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

# Queue example
$requestBody = Get-Content $triggerInput | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Output "PowerShell message body '$requestBody'"
$entity = [PSObject]@{
  PartitionKey = $requestBody.room  
  RowKey = get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s.ms"
  Temp = $requestBody.temp
}

$entity | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $outputTable
```

This results in one new entity (can be thought of as a row in database terms); assuming you've configured an Azure Table Storage output object in the Function and called it outputTable.

Comment: I've updated my answer, so you could better understand how to do that without powershell code